# SQL Server: Subtraction between 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 queries, where in one table the amount is shown for cars such as

```
Amount_Table        Cars 
800                 Car A
900                 Car B
2100                Car C
```

Second Table shows discount respectively for Car A, B & C.

```
Discount_table 
40 
10 
80
```

I wish to have a final query where in the Amount-Discount values are displayed

The amount table has one query made and discount table has another query. hence i wish to do 
`(amount-query) - (discount query)`

I did

```
Select ( (amount-query) - (discount-query))
```

but that threw error of 

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show us your actual table schema and actual SQL?

Comment: can you post the COMPLETE query? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
Select AmountTable.Amount-isnull(DiscountTable.Discount, 0)
from AmountTable left join 
on AmountTable.Car = DiscountTable.Car
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "subtract" queries. You have to do a join between tables (or subqueries), and make expressions using columns' names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join:

```
SELECT *
       ,cars_table.amount - discounts_table.discount
FROM cars_table
INNER JOIN discounts_table
    ON cars.some_key = discounts_table.some_key
```